# Fatal Exception : java.lang.NullPointerException. Error is occuring when i tried to hide the action bar menu items

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have tried to hide the action abr and its menu items after I made sure through toast that the menu's are inflated. But on trying to hide them, the menu_items are giving a problem....on commenting lines 118 and 119 it gives no errors but it dosent hide the menu_items which i want...please have a look

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);        
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.national, menu);        
    actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    m_weather = menu.findItem(R.id.weather);
    m_expand = menu.findItem(R.id.expand);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    init();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.weather:                                              
            break;
        case R.id.expand:
            hide(); //line 52
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

public void hide(){
    MyPreference.hide_menu_item = true;
    img_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    m_weather.setVisible(false);    //line 118: error at this line
    m_expand.setVisible(false);     //line 119
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}
```

LOGCAT

```
04-29 00:43:10.159: E/AndroidRuntime(2497): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 00:43:10.159: E/AndroidRuntime(2497): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 00:43:10.159: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at     tab_activities.NationalFragment.hide(NationalFragment.java:118)
04-29 00:43:10.159: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at    tab_activities.NationalFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(NationalFragment.java:52)
04-29 00:43:10.159: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at     android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:1586)
04-29 00:43:10.159: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:1994)
04-29 00:43:10.159: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:372)
04-29 00:43:10.159: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:986)
04-29 00:43:10.159: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
04-29 00:43:10.159: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
04-29 00:43:10.159: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
04-29 00:43:10.159: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:547)
04-29 00:43:10.159: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:115)
```

I have the similar code in the first fragment but it gives no error and it works perfectly...only in the second fragment(above) it gives these errors. Please help!

Comment: Please make sure the items m_weather and m_expand are not null.

Comment: Thanks...i got the problem....

Answer (score 0):

```
if (m_weather!= null){
    m_weather.setVisible(false);  
}
```